# Programmatically remove splitter from a Dojo tabContainer

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

How do I remove a splitter from a dijit tabContainer programmatically?

I have the layout which includes the tabContainer written decoratively in the mark up like so http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/4o0sfdzd/

I need a js solution that will allow me to remove the an existing splitter,
I've tried the following:

```
tabContainer.set({splitter : false});
```

and despite seeing the value set as false after inspecting the element I can still see and use the splitter in the web browser.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I see you are talking about removing the splitter from a child of a BorderContainer.  It doesn't matter if the child is a TabContainer or some other widget.

Unfortunately the `splitter` property is `const` so it's not as simple as `tabContainer.set({splitter : false});`.

But I think you can do it by calling `myBorderContainer.removeChild(tabContainer)`, then set `tabContainer.splitter` to false, and finally `myBorderContainer.addChild(tabContainer)`.

If the layout changes after the removeChild()/addChild() you will need to specify a position to `addChild()`, or specify `layoutPriority` on all your BorderContainer children.